# How can I convert bytes array to cp874 in Dart?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I use "HttpClientResponse" to get data from web site but charset is not utf-8,I want to convert response data (List) to CP874 or windows-874 charset. Now i try "utf8.decoder" it have error "FormatException: Bad UTF-8 encoding".

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.badCertificateCallback =
    ((X509Certificate cert, String host, int port) => true);
client
    .getUrl(Uri.parse("https://www.amr.pea.co.th/AMRWEB/Index.aspx"))
    .then((HttpClientRequest req) {
  return req.close();
}).then((HttpClientResponse resp) {
  print(resp.headers.toString());
  resp.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((text) {        
    print(text);
  });
});
```

error

```
E/flutter (12802): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(199)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (12802): FormatException: Bad UTF-8 encoding 0xbb (at offset 1963)
```

Comment: Write your own decoder. Take Latin1Decoder as an example and adapt it to implement a working javascript implementation like: https://github.com/mathiasbynens/windows-874/blob/master/src/windows-874.js

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error have you tried using this

```
utf8.decode(response.bodyBytes)
```

OR

Changing my project encoding to 'your desired' also fixed the problem.

File -> Other Settings -> Settings For New Project, then find "File Encodings", change Project Encoding to 'your desired'.(Did this in android studio)